# Which thread runs first?

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following code,

```java
public class Callme {

    public Callme() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    void callA(String msg) throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (this) {
             System.out.print("["+msg);
             Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }

    void callB(String msg) throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.print("{"+msg);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }

    void callC(String msg) throws InterruptedException
    {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.print("("+msg);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println(")");
    }

}
```

**Somewhere else:**

```java
public class Caller implements Runnable {

    public char msg;
    public Callme target;
    public Thread t;
    public Caller(char msg, Callme target) {
        this.msg = msg;
        this.target = target;
        t= new Thread(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            switch (msg) {
            case '[':
                target.callA("Hello");
                break;
            case '{':
                target.callB("Hello");
                break;
            case '(':
                target.callC("Hello");
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Somewhere else:**

```
        Callme target = new Callme();
        Caller ob1 = new Caller('[', target);
        Caller ob2 = new Caller('{', target);
        Caller ob3 = new Caller('(', target);

        ob1.t.start();
        ob2.t.start();
        ob3.t.start();
```

Assuming `callA` runs first, after its `synchronized`statement is executed, in my trials, always `ob1` next step is executed.
I thought sometimes `ob2` synchronized step should be executed before that(at least sometimes).

**Actual Output:**

```
[Hello]
{Hello}
(Hello)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[Hello(Hello]
)
{Hello}
```

Of course the order of `{,[` and `(` can vary and is not predictable.

Comment: If you are directly calling `t1.callA` etc, they will execute in the same thread, so there cannot be any interleaving.

Comment: @Andy Turner I was actually calling those functions from the run() of different threads.

Comment: `callA`  `callB` `callC` are all of those in same class?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's not clear how you are invoking the code.

Comment: YES.They are of same class.

Comment: The logical explanation is that the scheduler does *not* go "out of its way" to randomize the thread to execute. If your code takes a couple of milliseconds the scheduler probably decides not to switch thread at the end of the syncronized block and let the thread complete its time slot. However if you spawn other processes this might change. Also: how many cores does your machine have? If you have 8 cores then the scheduler might be more willing to run the 3 calls concurrently while if you have only 2 cores your program may be preferentially run sequentially on one core only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any job is restricted to adquire

```
synchronized (this) {
    <<job>>
}
<<after>>
```

and any job must run `<<job>>` before `<<after>>`.

To be multiple `<<after>>` interleaved (`<<job>>` is impossible), one `<<after>>` must be blocked at least, until other later `<<job>>` and `<<after>>` will be executed. Using your code is very unlikely (`<<after>>` take the time to print one character but `<<job>>` take one second).

No matter how, how many and when the methods are called.

To produce the desired behavior, you must to add the `blocking` after the synchronized code and before the `<<after>>` code.

```
class Call {
    public Call() {}

    private static void delay(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // keep out!
        }
    }

    private void call(char a, String msg, char b) {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.print(a);
            System.out.print(msg);
            delay(100);
        }
        delay(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10) * 10); // probability
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    void callA(String msg) { call('[', msg, ']'); }
    void callB(String msg) { call('{', msg, '}'); }
    void callC(String msg) { call('(', msg, ')'); }
}

public class Callme {
    static Call call = new Call();
    static List<Consumer<String>> calls = asList(call::callA, call::callB, call::callC);

    static void randomCall() {
        calls.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(calls.size())).accept("Hello!");
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        IntStream.range(0, 50).forEach(ignore -> new Thread(Callme::randomCall).start());
    }
}
```

With outout:

```
(Hello!)
(Hello!)
)
{Hello!{Hello!}
{Hello!}
}
[Hello!(Hello!]
)
(Hello![Hello!)
{Hello!]
(Hello!}
[Hello!)
[Hello!]
]
(Hello![Hello!)
(Hello!]
[Hello!)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the expected output is

```
[Hello]
{Hello}
(Hello)
```

1. Complete messages are expected because when leaving a synchronized block the code proceeds and immediately prints the closing character. Other threads do not continue that fast, first of all they have to get scheduled and then acquire the lock for the `synchronized` block, these steps take time
2. `Thread.start()` starts an OS-level thread (https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L673, https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L705, https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/native/java/lang/Thread.c#L44, https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#L2634, https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp#L420, the chain ending with a system-dependent `os::start_thread(thread);` line), so ultimately it is up to the operating system how fast and in what order the threads will run, but typically they start running soon and in the order they have been requested to start
3. `synchronized` uses object monitors, and they build a list of the threads which are waiting for them (https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L186 is the file, and the code is a bit out of this world, but the list itself is a linked list - well, a circular, doubly-linked one -, `_waitSet`, managed via the add/dequeue methods starting from https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/objectMonitor.cpp#L2251). So `notify()` and `notifyAll()` walk through that list and wake up other threads in a deterministic order.